# How to Stop Console logs from one particular file in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, console, firefox-developer-tools

Please Tell me the way to stop console logs from one file in firefox.
As you can see in attachment I am getting console logs from "redux-logger.js:1". How can i Stop them in firefox?

FYI - "I want other logs. In Chrome their is an option to Hide messages from one particular file where can I find that option in Firefox?"

[FireFox Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P84Vo.png)

[Chrome console with "Hide" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPX14.png)

Comment: I think firefox doesn't have this option.

Comment: There is a filter bar in the top of the console, same as on chrome

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Firefox's settings to skip files but you can achieve that with JS, I used Tampermonkey extension to block logging from certain files. You can add your files and domains.

So basically we use a Proxy to rewrite `console`'s methods with `noop` functions if the caller's file in our black list:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Skip console logging
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       silentmantra.ru@gmail.com
// @match        *
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const skipFiles = 'redux-logger.js Core.js index.js'.match(/[^\s]+/g);
    // if the file in any position in the stack - skip, otherwise skip if it calls console.<method>() only
    const skipAllStack = false;

    console = new Proxy(console, {
        get(console, prop){
            try{
                throw new Error();
            }catch(e){
                // get files in the stack
                const files = [...new Set(e.stack.split('\n').filter(Boolean).map(line => {
                    const parts = line.split('@');
                    return new URL(parts[1]||parts[0]).pathname.match(/[^/]+$/)[0]?.split(':')[0];
                }))].filter(Boolean);

                if(skipAllStack ? files.some(file => skipFiles.includes(file)) : skipFiles.includes(files[1])){
                    return ()=>{};
                }
            }
            return console[prop];
        }

    });

})();
```

Comment: Not working for me. Can not recognize Redux-logger because it is a middle ware in all Api calls so it gets logged no matter what.

Comment: @DhirajPatel fixed, try again